# Extract values from a complex column in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe which has a complex column, refer to below value:

```
ID  value
1   [{"label":"animal","value":"cat"},{"label":null,"value":"George"}]
```

I want to add a new column in PySpark dataframe which basically convert it into a list of strings. If Label is null, string should contain "value" and if label is not null, string should be "label:value". So for above example dataframe, the output should look like below:

```
ID   new_column
 1   ["animal:cat", "George"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transform` to transform each array element into a string, which is constructed using `concat_ws`:

```
df2 = df.selectExpr(
    'id',
    "transform(value, x -> concat_ws(':', x['label'], x['value'])) as new_column"
)

df2.show()
+---+--------------------+
| id|          new_column|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|[animal:cat, George]|
+---+--------------------+
```